# Updated Node version in GitHub Action not being picked up in PR checks

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the following action set up in my private GitHub repo:

```yaml
# This workflow will do a clean install of node dependencies, build the source code and run tests across different versions of node
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/using-nodejs-with-github-actions

name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.17.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
    - run: yarn test
```

Previously, the `node-version` was set to `[15.x]` and everything worked wonderfully. Since updating the required Node version to `14.17.x` I have a check in my PRs that never resolves. It says:

```
build (15.x) Expected — Waiting for status to be reported      Required
```

What am I missing here? It’s almost as if something is cached.

Comment: In the github action logs, you should see with what inputs the `setup-node` action is invoked. Can you please share that?

Comment: That’s part of the problem. In the “Checks” section in the PR it says, “build (15.x) Expected — Waiting for status to be reported” perpetually but there is no “Details” link next to it to view the associated log. When I go to the “Actions” tab in the repo, all workflows appear to have completed successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being a required status check that was added in “Settings » Branches » Require status checks to pass before merging » Require branches to be up to date before merging”. I removed that status check and re-added the updated version, then the message disappeared from the Checks list in all open PRs.